# How to Test Recovery in HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I wanted to test the recovery of data in HBase (Standalone mode), How can i do that? Will recovery works in Stand-alone mode?

After executing the put command from shell with out closing the HBase i switched of my VM and 
restarted, it's not showing the newly added data. Even i tried from eclipse also it's not showing. How can i test recovery in HBase? I am able to see the Hfiles, but not Hlog does i need to set any path for this?

This is the code i had written..

```
Put p=new Put(Bytes.toBytes("name10"));
p.setWriteAheadLog(true);
p.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes("Some Value 10"));
table.setAutoFlush(true);
table.put(p);
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

HLog files are stored in **.logs folder(Rootdir)**, In Stand alone mode it takes time to write into WAL where as in Pseudo Distributed or Distributed mode it will updates immediately